# Is there an alternative to Trie for my needs?

Tags: .net, data-structures, trie

I have a program that requires an ID to load a template.

The template is assigned based on the ID. Each template has a key, e.g. `tx`. IDs that contain this pattern will have this template assigned, e.g `tx-10000` or `tx_1000`.

I found that **Trie** can work for my needs, however after adding all my template keys to the Trie and then trying to match, it didn't work, because it needs to be reversed (assign ID to the trie and then search the trie for the template keys).

However I want something to work for my needs, so adding all the template keys to the Trie and then matching it by the ID. Something that I can add all the template keys: `tx`, `gn`, `dv` and then use a method to match a string like `tx-1337` or `gn_1302` that will match the specific template.

I'm using .NET if that's relevant.

What can I use to achieve this?

Comment: Can't you use a Dictionary/HashMap?

Comment: @trincot I could, but how would I match the key? `Dictionary.Keys.StartsWith`? I want something more efficient.

Comment: You want to match prefixes? I didn't get that from your question.

Comment: My understanding is that you have a list of template keys, something like `tx`, `gn`, `dv`, etc. Your input is a given ID, which has a prefix that matches a template key, then separated with the later part by a `-` or `_`. Then, you want to find the template key from the given ID. Is that correct?
If that's the case, could a split by the first index of `_` or `-` work?

Comment: @HungThai You are correct however I don't want split, I want something faster since this method will be called quite a lot hence why I considered Trie.

Answer (score 0):

A minor modification in the way we search the input in the Trie could fit your situation.

You can use the following tweaked trie (in C#).

```
public class Trie
{
    private readonly Node _root;

    public Trie()
    {
        _root = new Node('^', 0, null);
    }

    private Node Prefix(string s)
    {
        var currentNode = _root;
        var result = currentNode;
        foreach (var c in s)
        {
            currentNode = currentNode.FindChildNode(c);
            if (currentNode == null) break;
            result = currentNode;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public string FindTemplateID(string s)
    {
        return Prefix(s).StringValue;
    }

    public void InsertRange(List<string> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items) Insert(item);
    }

    public void Insert(string s)
    {
        var commonPrefix = Prefix(s);
        var current = commonPrefix;
        for (var i = current.Depth; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            var newNode = new Node(s[i], current.Depth + 1, current);
            current.Children.Add(newNode);
            current = newNode;
        }
        current.StringValue = s;
        current.Children.Add(new Node('$', current.Depth + 1, current));
    }
}

public class Node
{
    public char Value { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Children { get; set; }
    public Node Parent { get; set; }
    public int Depth { get; set; }
    public string StringValue { get; set; }

    public Node(char value, int depth, Node parent)
    {
        Value = value;
        Children = new List<Node>();
        Depth = depth;
        Parent = parent;
    }

    public Node FindChildNode(char c)
    {
        foreach (var child in Children)
            if (child.Value == c)
                return child;

        return null;
    }

    public void DeleteChildNode(char c)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < Children.Count; i++)
            if (Children[i].Value == c)
                Children.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Let's test that trie:

```
public void TestTrie()
    {
        var trie = new Trie();
        trie.InsertRange(new List<string> {"tx", "gn", "dv", "fz", "ab", "abc"});
        Console.Out.WriteLine(trie.FindTemplateID("tx-1234")); // Got "tx"
        Console.Out.WriteLine(trie.FindTemplateID("t-1234")); // Got null
        Console.Out.WriteLine(trie.FindTemplateID("gn_1234")); // Got "gn"
        Console.Out.WriteLine(trie.FindTemplateID("xx_1234")); // Got null
        Console.Out.WriteLine(trie.FindTemplateID("ab_1234")); // Got "ab"
        Console.Out.WriteLine(trie.FindTemplateID("abc_1234")); // Got "abc"
    }
```

Further optimization to improve the performance can still be done.